# Passing a variable to jQuery jsonp

Tags: jquery, jsonp

We have a database of college campuses and I'm trying to create links for each state. On our site it will be an SVG map that get's clicked on, but for demo purposes it's just a text link. I can't figure out how to wire this up.

I've hard coded in some json results to make sure that part of the code works but I'm not sure how to make it so when a link on the page is clicked it passes the state into the json request.

Here is the demo HTML

```
<a href="http://ml.uscm.org/ministries.json?state=WY&active=true&callback=Wyoming">Wyoming</a>
<a href="http://ml.uscm.org/ministries.json?state=WY&active=true&callback=Florida">Florida</a>

<span class="results"></span>
```

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonp = '[{"city":"Casper","enrollment":"4426","name":"Casper College","state":"WY","tuition":2232,"url":"http://www.campusventures.org","zip":"82601-2458","id":3928},{"city":"Riverton","enrollment":"2316","name":"Central Wyoming College","state":"WY","tuition":2472,"url":"","zip":"82501-1520","id":818},{"city":"Torrington","enrollment":"1965","name":"Eastern Wyoming College","state":"WY","tuition":2376,"url":"http://www.campusventures.org","zip":"82240-1699","id":819},{"city":"Cheyenne","enrollment":"5302","name":"Laramie County Community College","state":"WY","tuition":2640,"url":"","zip":"82007-3299","id":820},{"city":"Sheridan","enrollment":"4296","name":"Northern Wyoming Community College District","state":"WY","tuition":2398,"url":"","zip":"82801-1500","id":5825},{"city":"Laramie","enrollment":"13922","name":"University of Wyoming","state":"WY","tuition":4278,"url":"http://www.cvuw.com","zip":"82071-3434","id":4073},{"city":"Rock Springs","enrollment":"4013","name":"Western Wyoming Community College","state":"WY","tuition":1145,"url":"","zip":"82902-0428","id":823}]';
    var results = '';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
    $.each(obj, function () {
    results += "<h3><a href='http://ml.uscm.org/ministries/" + this['id'] + ".json" + "'>" + this['name'] + "</a></h3>";
    results += this['city'] + "<br/>";

    $('span.results').html(results);

});
```

});

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/richcoy/nfNMr/1/) of what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm mistaken, but do you mean simply pass the state as a variable into the JSON request, like this?

```
?state=" + this['state'] + "
```

http://jsfiddle.net/richcoy/nfNMr/1/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the var jsonp in my code needs to change to the basic url and get passed the state that was clicked. If you click on the link now it simply loads the results unformatted, I need them to display on the page the way my hard coded demo data is. Sorry if I'm not explaining this well.